# What is the best way to show a user that a social media account is linked?

Tags: website-design, buttons, social-media

I am working on a profile page where user can link their social media account (Twitter, Facebook. etc.) But what is the best way to show a user that his account is linked? Like a checkmark or something else?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I'd suggest to remove the Connect button like above and change it to an unlink button. Show them the linked account id and provide an **Unlink** button next to it.

[image: Unlink account by showing the linked account id and giving an unlink option]

In case you don't have an unlink option (which would be a bad idea), just don't show the linked option at all.

Comment: Good answer, but if there's not an unlink option (which I agree, there should be), I'd suggest just indicating that it *is* linked already, perhaps by showing it in a disabled state with some text indicating it has already been linked. This would communicate that it is an available option that has already been done, instead of making making it look like it's just not an option anymore.

Comment: @maxathousand Agreed